# Proving homotopy invariance of the contour integral

Tags: complex-analysis

> **Theorem:** Let $f:\Omega\to\mathbb C$ be a holomorphic function on some domain $\Omega$ and let $\gamma_0,\gamma_1:[a,b]\to\Omega$ be closed, piecewise $C^1$ curves. If $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_1$ are homotopic then
> $$
> \int_{\gamma_0} f(z)\,dz = \int_{\gamma_1} f(z)\,dz.
> $$

Our prof gives this proof:

> Let $\gamma, \gamma_* : [0, 1] \rightarrow \Omega$. Let $\Gamma$ be a differentiable mapping as in the definition of homotopy of $\gamma$, $\gamma_* $. Then
> $$\int_{\gamma} f(z)dz - \int_{\gamma_*} f(z)dz = \int_{\gamma_0} f(z)dz$$
> where
> $\gamma_0 = \Gamma \circ \tilde{\gamma_0}$,
> and $\gamma_0$ is a path that goes around the boundary of $[0, 1]^2$.
> For an $n \in N$, we subdivide $[0, 1]^2$ into $4n$ squares with side length $2^{-n}$. Let $C_n$ be the set of boundaries of these small squares. Then
> $$\int_{\gamma_0} f(z)dz = \sum_{\tilde{\gamma_n} \in C_n} \int_{\Gamma \circ \tilde{\gamma_n}} f(z)dz.$$
> If $n$ is large enough, then each path $\Gamma \circ \tilde{\gamma_n}$ is contained in a convex subset of $\Omega$ (use compactness for this). By Cauchy's integral theorem, version 2, it follows that this contour integral vanishes.

---

I do not understand this part:

> Then
> $$\int_{\gamma} f(z)dz - \int_{\gamma_*} f(z)dz = \int_{\gamma_0} f(z)dz$$
> where
> $\gamma_0 = \Gamma \circ \tilde{\gamma_0}$,
> and $\gamma_0$ is a path that goes around the boundary of $[0, 1]^2$.

First of all, I guess there is a typo and it should be:

> ... and $\tilde{\gamma_0}$ is a path that goes around the boundary of $[0, 1]^2$

However, why is that?

And I do not understand why compactness implies: If $n$ is large enough, then each path $\Gamma \circ \tilde{\gamma_n}$ is contained in a convex subset of $\Omega$